# filter out zeros in pivot table using vba codes

Tags: vba, excel

I have vba codes that help me to create pivot tables but now I encounter entries that have 0 values, showing as blank on pivot table but I would like to modify my codes so that I can filter out 0 values. In another word, I would like to make pivotitem to not show if values are 0 on the right side.

Please see picture for desire results. When I run my codes, there is no error, it seems like nothing happened.

```
'filter out zero
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("PivotTable")

    Dim pf2 As PivotField
    Set pf2 = Pvt.PivotFields("Price Range")

    Dim pi2 As PivotItem
    For Each pi2 In pf2.PivotItems
        pi2.Visible = Len(ws1.Range(pi2.DataRange.Address)) > 0
    Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above has many issues, mainly unassigned variables. If you use `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules, it will help you tremendously in learning to right correct syntax in your code.

This will work for you:

```
Option Explicit 

Sub FilterBlankPivotItems()

    Dim ws1 as Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("PivotTable")

    Dim pt as PivotTable
    Set pt = ws1.PivotTable("PivotTable1")

    Dim pf as PivotField
    Set pf = pt.PivotFields("PriceRange")

    Dim pi as PivotItem
    For each pi in pf.PivotItems
        pi.Visible = Len(ws1.Range(pi.DataRange.Address)) > 0
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Got it correct, I should replace Total Values to Price Range. That will do it. You are SUPER. saved the day, I did all different methods over the weekend and still had troubles. You just saved the day. Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to iterate through the PivotItems. Instead, you can just set a Values filter on the "Price Range" field to only display items than have a corresponding value of greater than zero.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterBlankPivotItems()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pfValues As PivotField

Set ws = Worksheets("SomeWorksheetName")
Set pt = ws.PivotTables("SomePivotTableName")
Set pf = pt.PivotFields("SomePivotFieldName")
Set pfValues = pt.PivotFields("SomeValuesFieldName")

pf.ClearAllFilters
pf.PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlValueIsGreaterThan, DataField:=pfValues, Value1:=0

End Sub
```

This is the same as doing this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, your codes also work like a charm. I actually have another question for pivot grouping but this time in percentages, if you are interested, please check it out.